# Javascript cookies in firebase+react app with connected domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, cookies

**Setup**

I have a react app (create-react-app) hosted in firebase.  The app asks the user for a zip code, stores it in a cookie, and displays weather data for that zip code.  I have a custom domain that I have linked to the firebase url through the firebase console.

**The Problem**

When visiting the firebase url, the cookie works as expected.  When visiting the app through the custom domain, the cookie doesn't appear to be set.  I *think* this is caused by the redirection from my domain to the firebase url.

**The Important Bits**

Code I'm using to set the cookie:

```
//static function taken from w3:
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";path=/";
}
//Called later in the app:
  setZip = zip => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      zip: zip,
      zipIsEntered: true
    }));
    setCookie("zip", zip);
  };
```

App link: [weather.nubgrammer.com](https://weather.nubgrammer.com)

Firebase link: [weather-app-1552191617462.firebaseapp.com/](https://weather-app-1552191617462.firebaseapp.com/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage might be closer to what you need. Cookies are for trips back to the same server, so you might be right about the redirect. I haven't used them too much, because local storage has suited my use cases.